# How to multiply two lists filled with zeros and ones, which represent binary numbers, but every size based combination of it

Tags: python, for-loop

So i have two lists of zeros and ones which represent binary numbers. and i want to multiply all valid binary numbers within these binary numbers with each other.

For example [1,0,1,1] and [1,1,0,1] would multiply

1011 * 1101 
1011 * 101 
1011 * 1

11 * 1101
11 * 101
11 * 1

1 * 1101
1 * 101
1 * 1

it would also stop if it would yield the right result, because this method is a test for another method.

I know that a for-loop within a for-loop could do that. But somehow I have problems transfering list to binary and then cutting down the binaries to the next number.

this is one of my first tries:

```
def multRes(a, b):
    
    la = len(a)
    lb = len(b)
    
   
    for i in range(la):
        
        r = int(''.join(str(x) for x in a), base=2)
        
        for j in range(lb):
            
            q = int(''.join(str(x) for x in b), base=2)
            
            p= r*q
            
            print(p)
            
            b.pop(0)
            
        a.pop(0)
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick. if someone could confirm i would appreciate it. It is a bit redundant but that's ok.

```
def multRes(a, b):
    
    
    r = int(''.join(str(x) for x in a), base=2)
    
    q = int(''.join(str(x) for x in b), base=2)
    
    la = len(a)
    lb = len(b)
    
    x = bin(r)
    
    y = bin(q)
    
   
    for i in range(la):
        
       
        
        for j in range(lb):
            
            
           p= int(x[i+2:],2) * int(y[j+2:],2)
           
           print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if it is what you want , but u can try:

```
a = [1, 0, 1, 1]
b = [1, 1, 0, 1]

la = len(a)
lb = len(b)

for i in range(la):
    a_bin = ''.join(str(x) for x in a[i:])
    r = int(a_bin, base=2)

    for j in range(lb):
        b_bin = ''.join(str(x) for x in b[j:])
        q = int(b_bin, base=2)

        p = r * q

        print(f"{a_bin} * {b_bin} = {p}")

a.pop(0)
```

Comment: thanks mate. that seems to work too. I decided not to use the pop so that i can keep the list.

Comment: Your welcome!
Please click the check mark on the left to indicate that this question is complete.